# Inserting Products data programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, product, curl

I'm getting product data from different store via curl call.Now i want insert all the product in my magento store. But only 3 products are inserting than i'm getting this error  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). Any help will be appreciated Thanks

```
<?php
   $mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';
    require_once $mageFilename;

 Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);      
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
   Mage::app();
   umask(0);

    $curl = curl_init();

    $API_ID          = "4";
    $API_URL         = "http://magento.com/component/controller.php";
    $App_key         = "as";
    $Functionname    ='get_product_list_by_category_id_and_or_vendor_id';
    $data            = 'data';


    $product_id='product_id';
    $name='name';
    $description='description';
    $short_d='short_description';
    $quantity='quantity';
    $weight = 'weight';
    $rate ='price';
    $sku='sku';
    $tax='tax_class_id';
    $visibility = 'Catlog, Search';
    $status='status';
    $meta_title='meta_title';
    $meta_description='meta_description';
    $meta_keyword='meta_keyword';
    $tag='tag';
    $model='model';
    $upc='upc';
    $ean='ean';
    $jan='jan';
    $isbn='isbn';
    $mpn='mpn';
    $location='location';
    $image='image';
    $stock='stock_status';





    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $API_URL,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Appid: 4",
            "Appkey: as",
            "Cache-control: no-cache",
            "Categoryid: 101,102,103,104",
            "Functionname: get_product_list_by_category_id_and_or_vendor_id",
            "Start: 0",
            "Limit: 2",
            "Postman-token: 7e0cbcb4-ad69-7f38-de10-f2387f8477ee",
            "Vendorid: 1474614118"
        ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $data_res = json_decode($response,true);
      //  echo $data_res;


       foreach($data_res[$data['get_product_list_by_category_id_and_or_vendor_id'] as $key){
           // echo $key[$product_id];

        $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product");
        $product 
        // ->setStoreId(0)
         // ->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
          ->setAttributeSetId(4)
         ->setTypeId('simple')
          //->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'))
          ->setSku($key[$sku])
         ->setName($key[$name])
          ->setWeight($key[$weight])
            ->setStatus($key[$status])
            ->setTaxClassId($key[$tax])           ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
          // ->setManufacturer(28)
           //->setColor(24)
           //->setNewsFromDate('06/26/2014')
         //->setNewsToDate('06/30/2016')
          //->setCountryOfManufacture('AF')
          ->setPrice($key[$rate])
           //->setCost(22.33)
           //->setSpecialPrice(00.44)
          //->setSpecialFromDate('06/1/2015')
            //->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2016')
          //->setMsrpEnabled(1)
             //->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1)
         //->setMsrp(99.99)
            ->setMetaTitle($key[$meta_title]) 
         ->setMetaKeyword($key[$meta_keyword])
            ->setMetaDescription($key[$meta_description])
           ->setDescription($key[$meta_description])
           ->setShortDescription($key[$short_d])

  //    ->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()))
   //    ->addImageToMediaGallery('media/catalog/product/1/0/10243-1.png', array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false, false)

   ->setStockData(array(
    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
    'manage_stock'=>1,
    'min_sale_qty'=>1,
    'max_sale_qty'=>2,
    'is_in_stock' => 1,
    'qty' => 999
    )
  )

       ->setCategoryIds(array(3, 7));
        $product->save();
           $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is proper. You need to debug the following section,

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$data_res = json_decode($response,true);
foreach($data_res[$data['get_product_list_by_category_id_and_or_vendor_id'] as $key){
```

Comment: i debugged the section that you pointed out. but still i didnt get any solution.

Comment: Are you sure you get value from $data_res[$data['get_product_list_by_category_id_and_or_vendor_id'] and $key[$sku]?

Answer (score 0):

There is a closing bracket missing after $data['...'] in this line:

```
foreach($data_res[$data['get_product_list_by_category_id_and_or_vendor_id'] as $key){
```

also make sure $data['get_product_list_by_category_id_and_or_vendor_id'] is set eg.

```
if(isset($data['get_product_list_by_category_id_and_or_vendor_id'])){
     //YOUR CODE
}
```